# Problem fitting TilePane's height and width to parent ScrollPane in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm building a `JavaFX` desktop app using scenebuilder for the UI.

Here i have a `tilepane` inside of a `scrollpane`, i couldnt use the "`fit to parent`" option from the context menu in scene builder, i guess the solution is to give them `-fx-id`'s and bind their `width` in the `controller` ?

I dont want to use any values so it all comes together nice when the user resizes the window.

how should i go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: What are you aiming to do?

Comment: bind the Tilepane's width to it's parent ScrollPane, i couldnt do this in scenebuilder

Comment: Use the `ScrollPane`'s [`fitToWidth` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#fitToWidthProperty).

Comment: oh god, it's that simple ? i feel stupid, Thank you